# Why redeclaration of variable is allowed inside loop and if condition which are declared out side of loop or if condition already?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int a=9;
    if(a<10){
        int a = 20;
        ++a;
        printf("%d\n",a);
    }
    printf("%d\n",a);
}
```

Why redeclaration of a is allowed in loop and if condition here?
Why can't we increment or decrement variable inside loop or if statement which are delclared outside of loop or if statement??

Answer (score 3):

It isn't a "redeclaration", it is a declaration of a brand new variable with the same name. All access to `a` within the if statement will refer to the new local variable `a` with value 20 and not to the previously allocated one with value 9.

The reason why it is allowed is because it allows you to give names to local variables without worrying about what names that are already taken elsewhere.

Mainly that is a concern between local scope and global scope, but the same rules apply recursively to local scopes inside the local scope.

If it wasn't allowed, it would be very hard to maintain large projects, as you would constantly run into naming collisions.

Generally though, it is considered very poor practice to give the same name to different variables in different scopes, you should avoid doing that whenever possible.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are expecting for changing i.e reassigning value of `a`, not a redeclaration. So, inside loop just do as `a=20` instead `int a=20`.

Redeclaration is not possible for same variable. Once declared any variable the memory is allocated for it. If you redeclare it will create conflicts or error.

Comment: I use int for 'a' twice so it is redeclaration.

Answer (score 0):

A variable inside a nested block can have the same name as a variable of the outer block. This is called name hiding.

The variable define in the nested block "hides" the variable of the outer block.

At the end of the nested block, the variable local to this block is destroyed. So the `printf` statement is executed with the variable defined at the beginning of the `main` function.